# including functions as a element in an if condition

Tags: python-3.x

can a function be used in an if condition like a normal variable during the initiation of an 'if' function?
I tried this in my program which didn't work.

```py
def choices():
    choice = input('Choose which path to take out... Think carefully  type left(l) or right(r) ').upper()

choices()
    
if choices() == 'LEFT' or choices() == 'L':
    print('left')
elif choices() == 'RIGHT' or choices() == 'R':
    print('right')
```

Comment: If you want to use your function as a value in a boolean condition, your function must return a value. In your case it doesn't not return anything.

Comment: thank you so much @Peterrabbit i didn't understand the answer given until I saw your comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As indicated in the comment, you need to return a value from `choices` function and then use it in the comparison. So an implementation like below will *almost* work right:

```
def choices():
    choice = input('Choose which path to take out... Think carefully  type left(l) or right(r) ').upper()

    return choice

if choices() in ["L", "LEFT"]:
    print('left')
elif choices() in ["R", "RIGHT"]:
    print('right')
```

In above case you ask for input twice if the first option will be `r` which is not good. So best way is to get user input only once per cycle and exit if a valid value was provided:

```
def choices():
    choice = input('Choose which path to take out... Think carefully  type left(l) or right(r) ').upper()

    return choice


while True:
    # Get input only once per cycle
    choice = choices()

    if choice in ["L", "LEFT"]:
        print('left')
        break
    elif choice in ["R", "RIGHT"]:
        print('right')
        break
```